# How to check if mpd is playing or stopped?

Tags: python, linux

I am using `python-mpd` to fetch current playing song artist and title. I am able to do that successfully.

The problem is after I stop playing song using `mpc stop` and than try to fetch current playing song info it shows the last playing song info.

*Get song info*

```
>>> client.currentsong()['artist']
'Sean Paul feat. Alexis Jordan'
```

*Now after I use mpc stop*

```
>>> client.currentsong()['artist']
'Sean Paul feat. Alexis Jordan'
>>>
```

So, my question is how do I make sure that mpd is currently playing or stopped?

What I need is that after `mpc stop` when I try to fetch song info it should show `None` or is there any method like `if mpd_playing()`.

I tried to look at the [`python-mpd`](https://github.com/magcius/python-mpd/blob/d75c186aed6aa613e5f8c6e379d6f9d39e844c5b/mpd.py) script but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> status = client.status()
>>> status['state']
'play'
# or
'pause'
# or
'stop'
```

So here is the condition you need:

```
if client.status()['state'] in ('play', 'pause'):
    #playing
else:
    #stopped
```